# Returning frequencies of words in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I think I have the right idea on how to solve this function, but I'm not sure
why I don't get the desired results shown in the docstring. Can anyone please help me fix this?

```
def list_to_dict(word_list):
'''(list of str) -> dict
Given a list of str (a list of English words) return a dictionary that keeps 
track of word length and frequency of length. Each key is a word length and 
the corresponding value is the number of words in the given list of that 
length.
>>> d = list_to_dict(['This', 'is', 'some', 'text'])
>>> d == {2:1, 4:3}
True
>>> d = list_to_dict(['A', 'little', 'sentence', 'to', 'create', 'a', 
'dictionary'])
>>> d == {1:2, 6:2, 8:1, 2:1, 10:1}
True
'''
d = {}
count = 0
for i in range(len(word_list)):
length = len(i)
if length not in d:
    count = count + length
    d[length] = {count}
    count += 1
return d
```

Comment: `d[length] = {count}` is definitely not what you want.

Comment: Why not? the length is the key and the frequency, which is count, is the value.

Comment: no, the length is the key, and the value is a *`set`* containing a single-element, which is an `int` representing the frequency.

Answer (score 2):

Using `Counter` definitely is the best option:

```
In [ ]: from collections import Counter
   ...: d = Counter(map(len, s))
   ...: d == {1:2, 6:2, 8:1, 2:1, 10:1}
Out[ ]: True
```

Without using "fancy stuff", we use generator expressions, something I consider to be equally fancy:

```
Counter(len(i) for i in s)
```

If by "ordinarily" you mean using for loops, we can do that like so:

```
d = {}
for i in s:
    if len(i) not in d:
        d[len(i)] = 1
    else:
        d[len(i)] += 1
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it ordinarily?

Comment: Define ordinarily. This only uses the standard Python library. If your problem is that you simply don't understand what's happening, I'd suggest taking a full beginner's course of Python.

Comment: I mean how could we do it using beginner stuff in python?

Comment: Define beginner stuff. `collections.Counter` is a relatively easy thing to understand by reading its documentation.

Comment: The input is a list though.

Comment: I'm aware; run the code with your list `s` that you provided. I don't see what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do a loop for any word in the list. In each iteration create new key with value `1` if the length is not in the dict as a key yet, otherwise increase the previous value for the key:

```
def list_to_dict(word_list):
   d = dict()
   for any_word in word_list:
      length = len(any_word)  
      if length not in d:
          d[length] = 1
      else:
          d[length] += 1
   return d
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionary comprehension to iterate over `s`, which now contains the length of its original elements:

```
s = ['A', 'little', 'sentence', 'to', 'create', 'a', 'dictionary']
final_s = {i:len([b for b in s if len(b) == i]) for i in map(len, s)}
```

Output:

```
{1: 2, 6: 2, 8: 1, 2: 1, 10: 1}
```

Simply:

```
new_d = {} 
for i in s:
    new_d[len(i)] = 0
for i in s:
    new_d[len(i)] += 1
```

Output:

```
{8: 1, 1: 2, 2: 1, 10: 1, 6: 2}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without map?

Comment: This is suboptimal as it iterates over `s` for each element in `s`, giving it a run time of `O(n^2)`.

Comment: @bigez why would you want to avoid `map`? You could by replacing it with a generator expression, but it would be pointless.

Comment: I want to see how you could do it ordinarily without using fancy stuff.

Comment: @bigez See my answer.

Comment: @Ajax1234 why iterate over `s` twice? Just throw an if statement into the for loop.

Comment: @Sebastian true, however, I am trying to make this as readable and understandable for the OP.